# MSSQL Select - Removicing Duplicates won't work

Tags: sql-server, select, duplicates

Hey I have some Problem with the "GROUP BY"-clause. It won't match up the "day"-column.

[number] => int
[date] => char(14)

The normal day formatting is as following:

```
20190424091650
20190424091550
20190424091450
20190424091350
20190424091250
20190424091150
20190424091050
20190424090950
20190424090850
20190424090750
20190424090650
```

Does anybody know why they wont change to something like this (highest number on specific day):

```
31  20190424
34  20190423
20  20190422
```

Query:

```
SELECT
[number],
SUBSTRING([date], 0, 9) AS "day"

FROM
[LOG_VISITOR]

GROUP BY
[number],SUBSTRING([date], 0, 9)

ORDER BY  SUBSTRING([date], 0, 9) DESC,[number] DESC
```

Output:

```
[number] [date]
31  20190424
28  20190424
27  20190424
26  20190424
15  20190424
14  20190424
34  20190423
14  20190423
13  20190423
12  20190423
11  20190423
10  20190423
9   20190423
8   20190423
7   20190423
6   20190423
5   20190423
4   20190423
3   20190423
2   20190423
1   20190423
0   20190423
20  20190422
19  20190422
```

Comment: It would help if you show your table structure so we can see what data types are in the various columns.

Comment: [number] => int
[date] => char(14)

Comment: Try `ORDER BY  SUBSTRING([date], 0, 9) DESC, abs([number]) DESC`

Comment: still the same output :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need somethings like that :

```
SELECT
Max([number]) as [number],
left([date],8) AS [day]

FROM
[LOG_VISITOR]

GROUP BY
left([date],8)

ORDER BY  left([date],8) DESC
```

if it's correct , you don't need order by `[number] DESC` because `left([date],8)` is unique

but i don't understand you need `Max([number])`  or `Count([number])` 
you mentioned that `(highest number on specific day)` but used `count` for column's header

Comment: Thanks, that is the perfect solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
    declare @table as Table
    (col nvarchar(14))
    insert into @table values (20190422091650)
    insert into @table values (20190422091550)
    insert into @table values (20190423091450)
    insert into @table values (20190423091350)
    insert into @table values (20190423091250)
    insert into @table values (20190423091150)
    insert into @table values (20190424091050)
    insert into @table values (20190424090950)
    insert into @table values (20190424090850)
    insert into @table values (20190424090750)
    insert into @table values (20190424090650)

    select count(col), cast(left(col,8) as datetime) as [date] from @table
    group by cast(left(col,8) as datetime)
```